# Flutter : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..27: 28

Tags: android, flutter, dart, slide, dismiss

Hello Everyone I am flutter beginner and while practicing the Swipe to dismiss option I have completed the below mentioned code and after deleting few Products I am receiving the below error, I tried to solve the problem but couldn't, Kindly provide me your valuable suggestions.

Below I have Attached the code and error for your reference.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..27: 28

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      MyHome.build. (package:flutterswipedismiss/main.dart:34:27)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1201:28)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1214:55)
...

## ...

Main.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items =
      List<String>.generate(30, (i) => "Product ${i + 1}");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Delete panna sidela thallu"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return Dismissible(
            key: Key(items[index]),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              items.removeAt(index);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Item Dismissed."),
                ),
              );
            },
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text("${items[index]}"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not understand the cause of the problem, but i was able to fix it by converting the `MyHome` widget to `StatefulWidget`, and calling `setState` on removing the item.

here is the new code:

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  final List<String> items =
      List<String>.generate(30, (i) => "Product ${i + 1}");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Delete panna sidela thallu"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return Dismissible(
            key: Key(items[index]),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              setState(() {
                items.removeAt(index);
              });
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Item Dismissed."),
                ),
              );
            },
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text("${items[index]}"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue thank you for your response.